# Apps usage stats on iOS

Tags: ios

I'm aware all the limitation associated to an app running on iOS, but I would like to know if there is a way to know the usage stats of all the apps without jailbreaking, but eventually with the ability to call private methods or using instruments (this is only for the sake of experimenting).

My best guess is that since in iOS 7 is available the background update feature that should adapt itself depending on the usage pattern of every single app,  iOS need to store some stats somewhere (but probably those database is encrypted and private cause otherwise it would be a privacy issue). Just to be more specific what I'm really interested in is the number of time an app as been launched and eventually the time spent on it.

I realize that there are a couple of Question of stack overflow that are asking this but are all dated years ago and maybe the situation is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to inspect the iOS Diagnostics tool. This tool has a lot of information about your device and I think that it's possible to access that data with a hack :)

Check out this article for more info: http://www.lyonanderson.org/blog/2014/02/06/ios-power-diagnostics/.